# how can I append to a file in Xcode 4 and where should the file be located?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, append

I'm working with Xcode 4 and I'd like my iphone 4 application to append a line to a file every time I run a test. Is there any fast way to do this? If so, where exactly am I allowed to write inside the iphone directory hierarchy?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you ever need to read this data back? I was going to suggest something like archiving an array, but that would just keep growing, and eventually loading the whole thing in to add one new entry could use a silly amount of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write inside the bundle of the iPhone application because that would break encryption. You can write in the `Documents` directory, or somewhere under `<apphome>/Library`.

Since `Documents` may become visible for the iTunes user if you add `UIFileSharingEnabled` to your `Info.plist`, and this is a file private to the application, adding the file under `Library` is better. Not that it matters much during testing. Apple documents related to this: [Technical Q&A QA1699: Storing Private Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1699/_index.html), [A Few Important Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12).

You can use this code in an iPhone application to append text to a file:

```
// get path to Documents/somefile.txt
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"somefile.txt"];

// create if needed
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
    [[NSData data] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
} 

// append
NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];
[handle writeData:[@"line of text\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```